# Use GMX IMAP and SMTP server for sending and reading mails in Java

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap

I am currently working on a Mailing system app in Java. I am using Java.Mail to read and send emails. I created an E-Mail Account class given by:

```
public EmailAccount(String emailId, String password)
    {
        super();
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password = password;
        
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.put("incomiongHost", "imap.gmx.com");
        this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

        this.properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.gmx.com");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.user", emailId);
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    }
```

The following method checks for different errors while signing in and then logins to the email:

```
public LoginResult login()
    {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() 
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(emailAccount.getEmailId(), emailAccount.getPassword());
            }
        };
        
        try
        {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(emailAccount.getProperties(), authenticator);
            Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(emailAccount.getProperties().getProperty("incomingHost"), emailAccount.getEmailId(),
                    emailAccount.getPassword());
            emailAccount.setMailStore(store);   // use to get mails
        }
        catch(NoSuchProviderException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return LoginResult.FAILED_BY_NETWORK;
        }
        catch(AuthenticationFailedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return LoginResult.FAILED_BY_CREDENTIALS;
        }
        catch(MessagingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return LoginResult.FAILED_BY_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return LoginResult.FAILED_BY_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
        }
        
        return LoginResult.SUCCESS;
    }
```

The problem I am getting into is that my code always shows AuthenticationFailedException. I have switched on the "allow POP3 and IMAP to send and receive mails" option in GMX but still the problem occurs with the correct credentials. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you're only setting SMTP properties, then trying to create an IMAP object.  These are not interchangable servers and protocols.  Make sure you set all the mail.imap properties as required as well.  You've also misspelled incomingHost in your property setting.

Answer (score 0):

@Max 's comment solves the problem. The main problem was that I misspelled "incomingHost" while adding it to the properties. The correct code for EmailAccount class would be:

```
public EmailAccount(String emailId, String password)
    {
        super();
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password = password;
        
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.put("incomingHost", "imap.gmx.com");
        this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

        this.properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.gmx.com");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.user", emailId);
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        this.properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    }
```